# Function as argument in python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I need to pass some function as argument in another function. So, I want to add current time to class attribute every second, for example

```
import time
class Measurement():
    values = []
    def add_value(self, value):
        print "added value"
        self.values.append(value)


def smart_delay(input_function,args):
    start_time = time.time()
    while 5 > (time.time() -  start_time):
        print "Calling function"
        input_function(args)
        time.sleep(1)

measurement = Measurement()

smart_delay(measurement.add_value,time.time())
```

Ok, but after checking contents of measurement.values, I get
`[1425980407.173, 1425980407.173, 1425980407.173, 1425980407.173]` - so values are the same!!!
What happened? And how to get proper values?

**Updated:**

Actually, this question is about the way to allow to call some function, passed as the argument to another function. What do you think about this:

```
import time

class Measurement():
    values = []
    def add_value(self, value):
        print "added value"
        self.values.append(value)


def smart_delay(input_function):
    start_time = time.time()
    while 5 > (time.time() -  start_time):
        print "Calling function"
        input_function()
        time.sleep(1)

measurement = Measurement()

smart_delay(lambda: measurement.add_value(time.time()))
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? You passed it the result of calling time.time(), that won't subsequently  change.

Comment: `smart_delay(measurement.add_value,time.time())` causes the same value to be passed as the argument to `measurement.add_value()` each iteration of your loop.

Comment: In Python all arguments are resolved / evaluated before function execution - in your case first argument would be `unbound method` instance, and second would be `float` returned by `time.time()`

Comment: So, there is no way to call function with arguments, returned from another function, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `time.time()` is executed before the call to `smart_delay(...)`, so `smart_delay(measurement.addvalue, time.time())` will first get the return value from `time.time()` and pass that forward to `smart_delay`.

You need to pass the `time.time` function itself, and call it inside of the `smart_delay` method, instead of passing its return value:

```
import time
class Measurement():
    values = []
    def add_value(self, value):
        print "added value"
        self.values.append(value)


def smart_delay(output_f, input_f):
    start_time = time.time()
    while 5 > (time.time() -  start_time):
        print "Calling function"
        output_f(input_f())
        time.sleep(1)

measurement = Measurement()

smart_delay(measurement.add_value, time.time)
```

Notice, that this is not the best way to do what you're doing, but it works.

---

Here's how I'd do it:

```
import time

# Why do you need a measurement class which only acts as a list anyways?
my_measurements = []

def repeat(duration, function, args=(), kwargs={}, interval=1):
    """Repeat a function call for the given duration."""
    start_time = time.time()
    while duration > time.time() - start_time:
        function(*args, **kwargs)
        time.sleep(interval)

def add_time_measurement(measurements):
    measurements.append(time.time())

repeat(5, add_time_measurement, (my_measurements,))
```

And if you want some prints, you can just add them in the `add_time_measurement` function.

Comment: It is a pity, that I cannot to call function like `smart_delay(some_expression)`, when some_expression can be any mixture of methods or function.

Comment: @artsin How would you expect it to work? In your case, how do you expect Python to know if you want to call the `smart_delay(time.time())` with the return value from `time.time()` or to call the function `time.time` over and over again? As you learn more Python, it'll only start to make sense that it works the way it does :) Simply because it doesn't work like you wanted it to, doesn't mean it's a pity.